# PHP - CURL - Connection refused

Tags: php, curl, cgi

I'm trying to connect to a remote service:

```
function test(){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://myhost.ddns.net/myfile.cgi');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 10000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch).'<br>';
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        print_r($info);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
    }

    // Close handle
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

But I get always this output:

```
    Curl error: Failed to connect to myhost.ddns.net port 10000: Connection refused
    Array
    (
        [url] => http://myhost.ddns.net/myfile.cgi
        [content_type] => 
        [http_code] => 0
        [header_size] => 0
        [request_size] => 0
        [filetime] => -1
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0
        [redirect_count] => 0
        [total_time] => 0.261142
        [namelookup_time] => 0.060601
        [connect_time] => 0
        [pretransfer_time] => 0
        [size_upload] => 0
        [size_download] => 0
        [speed_download] => 0
        [speed_upload] => 0
        [download_content_length] => -1
        [upload_content_length] => -1
        [starttransfer_time] => 0
        [redirect_time] => 0
        [redirect_url] => 
        [primary_ip] => 
        [certinfo] => Array
            (
            )

        [primary_port] => 0
        [local_ip] => 
        [local_port] => 0
    )
```

If I try to access http://myhost.ddns.net:10000/myfile.cgi on a browser, I get prompted with the user/pass auth and a 200code. It's just CURL not working...

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this remote service set up to be used with CURL?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, but I got this piece of code from a community and there's several people using the connection like that (same service using curl). I've also tried to use fsockopen() but I get the same result (connection refused)

Comment: Is the browser that can access it on the same system as the cURL client?  What if you `telnet myhost.ddns.net 10000` from the system you're running curl on?  Most likely will also show connection refused.

Comment: Actually I've set up a wamp server on my laptop and tested it from there.. and it works.. What kind of setting could be stopping me from access it it from the apache server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end my hosting was blocking the port 10000. I asked to unblock it and it works now.

Thanks people.